# Session state in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I am working on a web application which has 3 kinds of users.

To avoid multiple login of the same user I have used a signin column in the table which will become 1 after signin and 0 after signout. I have used session state to signout the user if he closes the browser window without signing out.

```
<system.web>       
  <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="15" cookieName="student"/>
```

Global.asax :

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
        int sid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["student"]);
        candidate.signoutUser(sid);
}
```

But there are three kinds of users. I am not able to add multiple `sessionState`. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: I didn't understand what is the relation between 3 kinds to users(roles) and multiple session state

Comment: There are three kind of users. Admin,Faculty and student . I want to avoid multiple login for all of them. I am using the above mentioned method to avoid mutliple login for student

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why you don't add user type to its session state ?

like this :

```
Session["user"] = "Strudent_" + userId;
```

and then parse your single session to find Id and user type :

```
var userType = Session["user"].ToString().split('_')[0];
var userId = Convert.ToInt32(Sessionp["user"].ToString().split('_')[1];)
```

But I recommend to use to session states :

- one for userId
- one for userType

you can also query for user type from database using userId if you don't want to use multiple session states too.

Comment: this will work. ty . Is there a way to add multiple session state. I am getting an error saying "Error 73 Sections must only appear once per config file. See the help topic <location> for exceptions."

Comment: no you should have only one sessionState  tag in your webconfig. just use one and remove  cookieName="student" from SessionState tag.